# Calendar invite is never sent to recipients

Tags: calendar

When creating a calendar entry and inviting a recipient an invite is never sent so the other attendees to the appointment are never notified.

Comment: Di you figure this out?? Im having the same issue. No email invitation is being sent to the recipients.

Comment: There was another post on the forum referring to setting up an SSL certificate which is meant to be a fix for the issue. i haven't had time to test due to time restraints and am using Exchange OWA - outlook web access - which removes the need to have any local apps for calendar and email etc. Its not a solution for everyone but it's the right fit for me atm.