# No Meeting invite is being sent to recipients

Tags: calendar

Im using Office365 with Evolution client Email.

I can see all my event in Elementary Calendar but when I create an event from it with recipients no invitation is being sent.

I have to manually add recipients directly from Office 365 website.

Similiar issue was posted here
[Calendar invite is never sent to recipients](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19599/calendar-invite-is-never-sent-to-recipients/22693#22693)